# Xcode Crash while "build and archive"

Tags: xcode, build, archive

i have snow leopard 10.6.3 installed via iAtkos..everything runs good even XCode as well.I can successfully build iPhone apps run them on the simulator and the device but when i use the "build and archive" option( for adhoc distribution or itunes connect ) XCode simply crashes..does anybody have a solution for this?
thanks in advance
btw XCode version 3.2.3(tried 3.2.3 as well same result,also in safe mode)
Mac OS X version 10.6.3

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, and it turned out it was caused by a variable of wrong type in info.plist. My short bundle version was created as int instead of string.

I was getting the warnings about it, but it didn't seem relevant since the crash happened only when archiving, and normal building worked fine, the app ran fine. I suggest you check your benign looking warnings, one of them could fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might try 3.2.4 (available now).